# template_redirect or admin-ajax.php?

Tags: plugin-development, ajax, wp-admin, hooks

My plugin needs to be reachable by the public and accept query vars. When called, it will run some backend db tasks, call a 3rd party API and sometimes redirect. Previously, I was using `template_redirect` to do this since it was an early hook with wp resources loaded and prior to any output being sent to the browser. I could make a call like this:

> http://www.example.com/?id=123&token=abc

This has been working fine in my dev environment. Lately, however, I've been wondering if this will cause problems or conflict with other plugins/themes also using `template_redirect`, or for other reasons I haven't considered. I also wonder if this is a best practice. As an alternative, I could do similar using `admin-ajax.php`, for example:

> http://www.example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=mytasks&?id=123&token=abc

Doing it this way, I wonder if new problems could arise with wp installed in custom locations, strange rewrite rules, plugins blocking wp-admin access, etc.

Is using `template_redirect` better/safer than calling `admin-ajax.php` directly? Is there a norm or best practice for receiving and processing front-end requests like this?

Comment: Just for interest: what's the response Content-Type of your action?

Comment: Content-Type is `text/html; charset=utf-8`

Comment: There is also [`admin_post_(action)`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_post_(action)), similar in operation to `admin-ajax.php`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that one out. Having read more and stepped through the WP code, I think `admin_post_(action)` is the way to go. `template_redirect` may be okay too, but it seems there's a chance another plugin using this hook triggers first and interferes. Also, I'm not certain whether different WP setups or server configs may cause problems with receiving query strings off the root domain. Calling a file directly, for example `admin_url( 'admin-post.php' )`, seems a more surefire avenue. `admin_post_(action)` uses fewer resources as well.